# Keep getting ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. Very confused

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting this ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error and i don't know what i'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated Here is my code:

```
select CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE as CUS_CODE,
CUSTOMER.CUS_AREACODE as CUS_AREACODE,
INVOICE.INV_NUMBER as INV_NUMBER,
SUM(LINE.LINE_UNITS*LINE.LINE_PRICE) as Amount
from LINE LINE,
INVOICE INVOICE,
CUSTOMER CUSTOMER 
where CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE=INVOICE.CUS_CODE
and INVOICE.INV_NUMBER=LINE.INV_NUMBER
group by CUS_AREACODE, CUS_CODE
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Also, I'm not sure what the question is.  There are exactly two unqualified column references in the query, so the answer looks obvious to me.

Comment: You have (at least) two tables that have a column named `CUS_CODE`. When you say `order by CUS_CODE`, which table's `CUS_CODE` do you mean?

Comment: @mustaccio i'm trying to use the CUSTOMER table. if i do `group by CUS_AREACODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE` it still gives me that error

Comment: You better to state where the column comes from, like mustaccio said. And not just `CUS_CODE`, but all columns.

Comment: What's the logic of aliasing a table by the table's original name?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect it's the `GROUP BY`. First you'll need to add all the fields which aren't used in the summation. Second, you should specify the table or alias on all fields in the `GROUP BY`. Change your statement to

```
SELECT c.CUS_CODE as CUS_CODE,
       c.CUS_AREACODE as CUS_AREACODE,
       i.INV_NUMBER as INV_NUMBER,
       SUM(l.LINE_UNITS * l.LINE_PRICE) as Amount
  FROM CUSTOMER c
  INNER JOIN INVOICE i
    ON INVOICE.CUS_CODE = CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE
  INNER JOIN LINE l
    ON l.INV_NUMBER = i.INV_NUMBER
 GROUP BY c.CUS_CODE,
          c.CUS_AREACODE,
          i.INV_NUMBER
```

and see if that doesn't get it. Note that I changed the aliases so that they're short but easily understood, and changed the joins to ANSI-style joins instead of the old implicit joins.

Best of luck.